# I wanted to port my code with factorials from python to c ++

Tags: c++

C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void factorial(int a){
    int f = 1;
    for(int i = 1;i<=a; i++){f*=i;};
    cout << f << endl;
}

int main()
{
    factorial(number);
}
```

Python:

```
def factorial(a):
    f=1
    for i in range(1,a+1):
        f*=i
    return f
n=str(factorial(num))
print(n+"\n\n\n")
```

What am I doing wrong? I cant take normal answers from C++ after 15! In python this works ideal to 17000!
I'm sorry if the question is stupid. I begin to work with C++ only today

Comment: i tried using long int and it helped a little

Comment: You could also try `unsigned long long`, which may get you a bit farther.

Answer (score 5):

Python integers grow automatically to accommodate huge numbers. But in C++, integer types are of fixed sizes. Since the factorial function gets into huge numbers very quickly, it's very easy to overflow C++ integer types.

In order to work with such large numbers in C++, you'll need some kind of big integer library.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine in C++, the issue is that you are used to arbitrary sized numbers in Python, whereas C++ has a 32-bit or 64-bit limit on int. factorial(17000) is too big for C++ int. You will need to find a big number library in C++ or be satisfied with only computing factorials of small numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void factorial(int a)
{
    int f = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i<=a; i++)
    {
        f *= i;
    }
    cout << f << endl;
}

// Slight modification to allow for proper debugging.
// Just added a cin statement so you aren't passing a nonexistent parameter.
int main()
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    factorial(num);
}
```

I'm not sure about Python, but in C++, there is a max value for `int` variables.  It varies for different compilers, but mine is 2,147,483,647.  Because of how quickly the factorial function can grow, the highest value my compiler would be able calculate accurately using `int` variables will be `factorial(12)`.  `factorial(13)` would try to calculate a value larger than 6 billion, while `factorial(12)` stays below 1 million.

Comment: C++ does not specify the maximum number of `int`. It just sets a lower bound for it (and thats not 2,147,483,647)

Comment: @idclev463035818 `INT_MAX` returns 2147483647 and `INT_MIN` returns -2147483648

Comment: on your implementation yes. Different values are allowed

Comment: Really?  That's actually quite interesting.  I had no idea.  Thanks for the clarification.